# Accessing a soap xml node in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

After breaking my head on a wall for a whole day i just think i need some help for this.
I'm receiving the following answer from a soap call :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <SearchBrochuresResponse xmlns="http://services.iceportal.com/service">
            <SearchBrochuresResult>
                <pageNumber>0</pageNumber>
                <brochures>
                    <SearchBrochure>
                    <iceID>10427</iceID>
                    <city>Acapulco</city>
            </SearchBrochure>
        </brochures>
    </SearchBrochuresResult>
</SearchBrochuresResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried all i could find on the subject on stackoverflow and all the other sources i found, but i couldn't access to the iceID, basically my goal is to get into a php variable the value of the iceID node.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your xml data is in the variable `$data` you could create a simple XML object from it, then access it's nodes in the following way (example to get `iceID`):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

$iceID = (string)$xml->children('soap', true)
    ->Body->children()
    ->SearchBrochuresResponse
    ->SearchBrochuresResult
    ->brochures
    ->SearchBrochure
    ->iceID;
```

Comment: Flawless !!
Thanks a lot mate, you saved me from breaking my head on my desk !!
Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

You could look into XPath, the technique used to navigate and select parts of an XML document.
[Wikipedia on XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

If you need more help please post a more specific question. What have you tried? Do you only need to extract that specific value?

Comment: Yeah i tried the XPath way but couldn't get it working.